# Android Things Launcher does not show IP address

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3

I have Android Things running on my Raspberry Pi 3. I can see the Launcher but there is no IP address. I did not connect my Raspberry to an Ethernet cable to my local network. Please help :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so as I thought. The Raspberry Pi has to be connected to the same network as your local machine. This will give you the IP address in the bottom of the screen. Connection works like a charm :)

Comment: Hello Piotr, 

What do you mean by "The Raspberry Pi has to be connected to the same network as your local machine" ? How do you configure the wifi just after writting the image ? Or did you connect via ethernet ?

Many thanks
Marc

Comment: I used Ethernet to connect to the same network as my laptop. After that you can connect to the Raspberry using adb and then changed to wi-fi as they mentioned on Andriod Things website. Cheers!